# Java Binary Search Tree with Nodes that contain Linked Lists

Tags: java, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a Java program that will create a Database using a Binary Search Tree whose keys will be the make of a car (Chevy for example). And that node will contain a Linked list that will contain more detailed information about the cars.

My cars are added in a Linked List class called DBTreeNode.

Can I modify the BST implementation [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/BST.java.html), to make the data of the Node be a Linked List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add your DBTreeNode List as a member of BST Node along with other fields like Left, Right, etc... Then add accessors (getter, setter) for DBTreeNode. Hope this helps. Good Luck!

Here is an Example:

```
public class BST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {
    private Node root;             // root of BST

    private class Node {
        private Key key;           // sorted by key
        private Value val;         // associated data
        private Node left, right;  // left and right subtrees
        private int N;             // number of nodes in subtree
    private DBTreeNode VehicleDetails; // your list

        public Node(Key key, Value val, int N) {
            this.key = key;
            this.val = val;
            this.N = N;
    this.VehicleDetails = new DBTreeNode(); // initialize your list
        }

    public DBTreeNode getDetails(){
        return this.VehicleDetails; 
    }

    public void addDetails(DBTreeNode details){
        for(DBTreeNodeElement detail : details) this.VehicleDetails.add(detail);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was thinking, I'm just getting confused in the implementation. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: That helps me get started. Now my only issue is I'm having trouble traversing the tree to see if the details are adding correctly. Am I missing an easy toString method that I could try?

Comment: Actually never mind I figured it out. Thank you for your help!